# adding double click to draggable/droppable :: javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two boxes side by side, even though the code works I would like to add a double click animate flourish.

```
here is the jsfiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Kqse/

how would I go about adding a double click to the code I already have so that as well as dragging and dropping a double click would animate the icons into the boxes.

Maybe it could be done with css?? any ideas?

thanks :)

Comment: What are you stuggling with? From your jsFiddle you already animate the boxes to a certain point when they aren't dropped on a side. Why not just do the same thing on a dblclick jQuery event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. You can change the kind of jQuery animation. You can checkout this link to see the different kinds of animations:
http://api.jquery.com/show/
Hope this helps.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
revert: "invalid"
})
.dblclick(function(){
   $('.BtnReport').show();
    if ($(this).parent().attr("id") != "drop") { 
     $(this).hide().appendTo("#drop").show('slow');
    } else {
     $(this).hide().appendTo("#grid").show('slow');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8qyF/

Comment: I had to modify this a tiny bit to stop the icons dropping in a list, apart from  that. This works well. Thank you :)

` $(this).hide().appendTo("#drop").show('slow').css({ top: 0, left:0, display: 'inline-block' });`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore.  Here is my code:
`$("#" + divPopupDialogId + "-popup").draggable({
                cancel: ".PopupBody, .ui-link, .ui-btn, .ui-flipswitch",
                iframeFix: true, // Required for the iFrame events to work correctly
                containment: "#" + divPopupDialogId + "-screen",
            }).dblclick(function () { console.log("dblclick"); });`